# Difference in BATTLEFIELD 4 endings

Tags: battlefield-4

Has anyone tried the 3 possible endings on BF4? What are the differences between them? Is one preferable because the ending is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation - just replay the last mission multiple (3) times and see for yourself. You will also unlock weapons which you can use in multiplayer.

The 3 Weapons are:

QBZ-95-1

P90

M249

How to get them:

> kill Hannah, let the Valkyrie be destroyed, or kill Irish.

Comment: Granted we all know he/she should try them all on his own you could have at least gave some info on them.

Comment: Well, the spoiler is pretty much all that changes, which happens in the last minute of the last mission (Way to pad out your ending). If you insist, I'll write up what happens, it won't be interesting, though.

Comment: Not that I insist I was just saying really, that way it answers the question more.

Comment: Yeah, but It really just boils down to - someone dies, someone else dies, many people die.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much else to add.  The campaign was awful (like most shooter campaigns) and literally the only difference or choice in the game is in the last 60 seconds of the game.  That's it.